# Is there a way to retrieve private key of ganache account with web3?

Tags: web3js, accounts, private-key, ganache-cli

`web3.eth.getAccounts()` returns list of accounts.

Is there a way around to get the private key of one of the account from the list returned from the above code?

Comment: If there was a way, then it would make the entire Ethereum cryptography useless.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot get the private key from `web3.eth.getAccounts()` directly, but there's a few workarounds to do this with ganache:

1. Specify a mnemonic phrase with the `-m` option, e.g. `ganache-cli -m "stereo consider quality wild fat farm symptom bundle laundry side one lemon"`, this will derive private keys from the mnemonic phrase (with the derivation path `m/44'/60'/0'/0/n`.
2. Use the `--account_keys_path` option to save all private keys to a file, e.g. `ganache-cli --account_keys_path keys.json`. This will result in a JSON file with all addresses, private keys and public keys.
3. Use the `--account` option to manually specify a private key and balance, e.g. `ganache-cli --account "0x31c354f57fc542eba2c56699286723e94f7bd02a4891a0a7f68566c2a2df6795,1000000000000000000"`. This will assign 1 ETH (= 1000000000000000000 Wei) to the address corresponding to this private key. You can use the `--account` option multiple times, with different private keys.

Comment: How could you do the same things on js file? const ganache = require("ganache-core"); const mnemonicPhrase = 'dfafas' then

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Ganache CLI documentation](https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/ethereum-and-clients/ganache-cli/), during the setup of your ganache instance you can specify a path to save the accounts and private keys to.

```js
 ganache.server({ account_keys_path: "src/accounts.json" });
  return await new Promise<Web3>((resolve) => {
    server.listen(8545, () => {
      console.log("Ganache running at http://localhost:8545");
    });
  });
}
```

The `account_keys_path` argument will specify the relative path of the file you'd like the accounts and private keys to be written. This can be done when using `ganache.provider` aswell.

The documentation also mentions that you can pass an 'accounts' object itself, where you specify the accounts and private keys manually, but I have not tested this approach.